# Oracle global temporary table

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

Is there any way in Oracle to create a global temporary table which gets dropped after end of session? I know how to create temporary table with condition that rows are being deleted, but it is insufficient for me.

Comment: You can, sort of (but the drop has to be manual), but it isn't a good idea to create objects on the fly. Perhaps you can explain why you think you need to do this. If you've come from another DBMS that does allow this you might want a different approach for Oracle - maybe subquery factoring, maybe collections, maybe something else. It really depends on what you're doing and what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Please explain why that is "insufficient" for you. What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is that I am creating many temporary tables only so that I can export data from them and after some time my schema becomes full of unnecessary tables called "temp", "temp1", etc. Would be nice if Oracle had something like "work library" in SAS, which totally disappear after disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Postgres' way. Unfortunately, it is impossible in Oracle. Try to use [PL/SQL Collections and Records](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm)

Comment: Why is it "unfortunate"? The fact that global temporary tables are retained (it's the data that is temporary) is a feature.

Comment: As an example: when you have restrictions of creating new permanent objects (tables && types). In this case, you will use collections, without accessing by SQL: **from table(collection)**. It is really inconvenient.

Comment: Why would you have restrictions of creating new permanent objects? That's a problem for whoever has imposed silly restrictions on you, not a problem with the way Oracle has designed GTTs.